# Using "Queue" in C# for sending SMS

Tags: c#, queue

I am trying to send SMS to clients from transactional data. It works fine but sometimes the staging table gets tanked due to huge data load. I was thinking if there is any way to queue data in a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) order. I am still learning C#. Please help me to implement the following code in a smart way.
I am sharing what I did.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var datetime = DateTime.Now;
    var hr = datetime.Hour;
    var mm = datetime.Minute + 1;
    var ss = double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSTIME"]);

    // For Interval in Seconds 
    // This Scheduler will start at current time + 1 minute and call after every 3 Seconds
    // IntervalInSeconds(start_hour, start_minute, seconds)
    SchedulerTasks.IntervalInSeconds(hr, mm, ss,
        () =>
        {
            CreateNewSms.Instance.PostNewSmsText();
        });

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public async void PostNewSmsText()
{
    var smsDt = await Task.Run(() => DataAccessLayer.Instance.InsertSmsDataToLocalDb());

    if (smsDt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        var smsData = GetSmsData(smsDt);
        var xmlRespDoc = new XmlDocument();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var sms in smsData)
            {
                var smsText = GetSmsText(sms.Channel, sms.AccountNumber, sms.Amount, sms.DrCr, sms.CurrentBalance, sms.BranchName,
                    sms.CurrencyName, sms.TrnDescription, sms.UbsTrnDateTime);

                var smsSubmitTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var response = ExecuteSmsService.Instance.PostSmsText(sms.MobileNo, smsText, sms.TrnRefNo);

                var smsDeliveryTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var operatorInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Operator"];

                xmlRespDoc.LoadXml(response);
                var smsCsmsId = xmlRespDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SMSINFO/CSMSID")?.InnerText;
                var smsRefNo = xmlRespDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SMSINFO/REFERENCEID")?.InnerText;
                var smsDeliveryStatus = xmlRespDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SMSINFO/MSISDNSTATUS")?.InnerText;

                if (smsRefNo != null) //Save response data if sms delivery successful
                {
                    DataAccessLayer.Instance.InsertSmsResponseDetails(
                        sms.EntrySerialNo,
                        smsCsmsId,
                        smsRefNo,
                        smsText,
                        smsSubmitTime,
                        smsDeliveryTime,
                        true,
                        "Success",
                        operatorInfo);

                    DataAccessLayer.Instance.UpdateSmsStatus(sms.EntrySerialNo);
                    DataAccessLayer.Instance.DeleteSmsData(sms.EntrySerialNo, true);

                    Console.WriteLine("SMS successfully sent to: " + sms.MobileNo);
                }
                else
                {
                    //If any sms delivery failed here we set a counter to retry again in next date
                    DataAccessLayer.Instance.SetSmsCounter(sms.EntrySerialNo);

                    //Save response data if sms delivery unsuccessful with failed status
                    DataAccessLayer.Instance.InsertSmsResponseDetails(
                        sms.EntrySerialNo,
                        smsCsmsId,
                        null,
                        smsText,
                        smsSubmitTime,
                        smsDeliveryTime,
                        false,
                        smsDeliveryStatus,
                        operatorInfo);

                    DataAccessLayer.Instance.DeleteSmsData(sms.EntrySerialNo, false);

                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid mobile no: " + sms.MobileNo);
                }
            }
        });
            
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for transactions.....");
    }
}
```

I was searching on Queue Implementations and found this but confused how to use it here in my code.

```
public class SendSmsQueue
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<object> _jobs = new ConcurrentQueue<object>();

    public SendSmsQueue()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnStart));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Enqueue(object job)
    {
        _jobs.Enqueue(job);
    }

    private void OnStart()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_jobs.TryDequeue(out object result))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `DataAccessLayer` ? Is it EntityFramework, or Dapper, or SqlCommand or something else?

Comment: @Neil, it's simply SqlCommand.

Comment: How many messages (and size) are you sending?  SMS are small messages and you should not be backing up.  How close are you to a base station?  The SMS modem has to be make connection to a base station.  It sound like the bae station is not acknowledging your connection.  A simple fifo can be created using a List<>,  You always add to the end of the list and remove using  RemoveAt(0);

Comment: "staging table gets tanked" what does this mean?   Modern databases can hold billions of rows without a sweat.  I'm guessing that with a large number of messages to send `PostNewSmsText` doesn't finish before the timer kicks it off again, which will probably try and get all the outstanding messages (including the ones that the previous call hasn't finished yet), and therefore you are trying to send multiple, duplicate messages.

Comment: it a simple 160 characters sms message. It's connect a third party soap based sms service provider. I do get transactional data as sms text from a oracle table and then do staging into a sql server table. When sms successful sent I do keep those messages in another table for reporting purpose and delete from staging table. Since sms data comes as bulk amount I do get duplicate data which I do handle using Merge sql command. But I don't think it's working properly. So I was hoping if I could manage it through queues.